Print in WPF Application with PDF preview
I am developing a WPF application where I need to generate a PDF and open it in a Print dialog with a preview, so the user can either print or download it as a PDF. I haven't been able to find many resources related to handling PDFs, but I have managed to open a dialog box with an XPS document. However, the document preview is not displaying correctly, as shown in the screenshot below:

below is the code for open print dialog with xps
public void PrintXps()
{
    FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("Hello, this is a sample document.")));
    doc.PagePadding = new Thickness(50);
    doc.PageWidth = 800;
    doc.PageHeight = 600;

    string tempXpsFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".xps";

    try
    {
        using (var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(tempXpsFilePath, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            var xpsWriter = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);
            DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator;
            xpsWriter.Write(paginator);
        }

        var xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(tempXpsFilePath, FileAccess.Read);
        FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocSeq = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            printDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDocSeq.DocumentPaginator, "Printing XPS Document");
        }

        xpsDoc.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        File.Delete(tempXpsFilePath);
    }
}

To summarize, my goal is to create a PDF and open the print dialog with a print preview for it. Does anyone have an idea of how I can achieve this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

The viewer for the "FlowDocument" should be sufficient (WYSIWYG). The "pdf" (and driver) are not part of .NET proper. It's a 3rd party you deal with. In other cases, one creates "visuals" of whatever is on the screen; that can be saved; merged with documents; printed; and / or spun into a pdf (after the fact). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
